# Can I publish salt of a password?

Tags: php, .net, hash, crypt

I have a PHP website storing user passwords encrypted and salted.

Method used is **`crypt($password, $salt)`**. Salt is generated randomly.

Result is something like

```
$2a$08$saltsaltsaltsaltsaltsaltsaHashHashHashHashHashHashHash
```

Now I have to login to this database using something different than PHP, e.g. .NET. Problem now: `crypt()` does not exist in .NET.

I am now thinking of rewriting `crypt()` in .NET and extract the salt from above password-hash.

Is it safe to make the salt used for hashing a password publicly available? Or do I weaken security extremely?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "public" here - you always need to know the salt in order to check a password, as you encrypt the user-entered password with the same salt and check that the result is the same as the original result.

Comment: public means, that e.g. to send the salt to anybody asking for it. A user could then recreate its own passwordhash on a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sending the salt to anyone asking for it is insecure. Knowing it makes the number of possible values to guess much smaller and it is much easier to use brute force attacks to guess the original unsalted password. See [this answer in security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt#answer-17435) for more details.